# Indexing issue for output matrix in conv2(input,filter)

Tags: matlab, 2d, convolution

I am looking for a way to declare center of my kernel/filter so that the output of my 2D convolution is in accordance with the following figure

source: http://machinelearninguru.com/computer_vision/basics/convolution/image_convolution_1.html
[image]

I have looked into **conv2(input,filter)** but found that this inbuilt function assumes that for an MxN filter, its *center* is always located at (M,N) location in filter matrix. I saw the following image at https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/2dconvolution.html
. In this case the result of double sum will be located at (2,2) instead of (1,1) in output matrix

[image]

*Matlab Version:* **MatlabR2014a**

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly you need to use the shape handle in conv2:

```
conv2(input,filter,'same')
```

Comment: Yes.....it seems to work when M,N (filter matrix dimensions) are odd and maximum value in 'filter' lies middle. e.g when M=N=3 and max(filter) is at (2,2). However what if max(filter) is not at middle. For 3x3 example, let max be at (2,1). In that case 'same' handle does not work. Is there a way to ensure that output index is dictated by the location of max element of filter matrix? I thought of generating newfilter by zero padding filter matrix to bring max element of filter matrix in center and then use conv2(x,newfilter,'same')...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `'full'` shape argument of `'conv2'` and then index into the output to select whichever properly aligned slice you want.